# How to: soil moisture measurement with WaterMark?

Tags: sensors

I am new with Arduino, and i cant find documentation about how to connect Arduino with Watermark successfully.

I would like to connect my Arduino UNO with a watermark like this:

http://guideimg.alibaba.com/images/shop/72/08/19/4/watermark-soil-moisture-sensor-w-15-cable_3234944.jpg

Does anyone know any schema or documentation about how to do it? Have anyone tried it before?

I have found this: https://oceancontrols.com.au/datasheet/davis/ECS-014_07395-158_IM_06440_6470.pdf

but still not clear how to do it in Arduino.

Thanks you for your time.

Comment: The link to the PDF is not found, and the only other thing provided is a JPG image of the sensor, which is not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can google 
"Arduino-based system for soil moisture measurement"
and the author about this paper is "Vuk Radman" .
[image]
Now, I am also try to find the method using Arduino to connect WaterMark 200ss Sensor. The paper I share to you is what I have found from GoogleScholar, but I haven't used this method yet. Nevertheless, I think the method mentioned in the paper is feasible. Hopefully, this information can help you.